# MVVM WPF ObservableCollection : Error addign items, ItemsSource binding

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox, itemssource

I'm having troubles adding items to an ObservableCollection while using a listbox with ItemsSource.  I add dummy data for testing in my viewmodels constructor.

My viewmodel:

```
public class KabaDeviceListViewModel : KabaBase
{

    private ObservableCollection<KabaDeviceDetailViewModel> _details;

    public ObservableCollection<KabaDeviceDetailViewModel> KabaDevices
    {
        get { return _details; }
        set 
        {
            if (value != _details)
            {
                _details = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("KabaDevices");
            }
        }
    }


    public KabaDeviceListViewModel()
    {

        ObservableCollection<KabaDeviceDetailViewModel> _details = new ObservableCollection<KabaDeviceDetailViewModel>();

        KabaDevice kd1 = new KabaDevice("localhost A", "127.0.0.1", true);
        KabaDeviceDetailViewModel dvm = new KabaDeviceDetailViewModel(kd1);
        _details.Add(dvm);

        KabaDevice kd2 = new KabaDevice("localhost B", "127.0.0.1", true);
        KabaDeviceDetailViewModel dvm2 = new KabaDeviceDetailViewModel(kd2);
        _details.Add(dvm2);

        this.KabaDevices = _details;
    }
}
```

So far so good, but an error occurs in XAML code here, on ItemsSource of the listbox.  I don't see what I'm doing wrong. I use VS2010 and .NET 4.0.

```
<UserControl x:Class="KabaTest.View.KabaDeviceListView"
         ...
         xmlns:myViewModels="clr-namespace:KabaTest.ViewModel"
         xmlns:myViews="clr-namespace:KabaTest.View">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <myViewModels:KabaDeviceListViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <ListBox Margin="5" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=KabaDevices, Mode=TwoWay}" >
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myViewModels:KabaDeviceDetailViewModel}" >
                <myViews:KabaDeviceDetailView DataContext="{Binding }"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

The InnerException at ItemsSource is : {"Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead."}. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you have any other code in your app that tries to Add/Remove items directly to/from the ListBox rather than using the KabaDevices property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a problem in your constructor. Your assigning the backing field `_details` to the public property for that backing field `KabaDevices`. Not 100% sure whether this is the reason for the exception, but everything else should work fine, as far as I can tell. Try this:

```
public KabaDeviceListViewModel()
{

    var details = new ObservableCollection<KabaDeviceDetailViewModel>();

    KabaDevice kd1 = new KabaDevice("localhost A", "127.0.0.1", true);
    KabaDeviceDetailViewModel dvm = new KabaDeviceDetailViewModel(kd1);
    details.Add(dvm);

    KabaDevice kd2 = new KabaDevice("localhost B", "127.0.0.1", true);
    KabaDeviceDetailViewModel dvm2 = new KabaDeviceDetailViewModel(kd2);
    details.Add(dvm2);

    this.KabaDevices = details;
}
```

Comment: as you hinted this is not the reason for the error.  The this.KabaDevices = _details; in the @user2135342 code is ineffective as the if (value != _details) would never be true.  I suspect the real error is in code that we cannot see.  Your code change suggestion is spot on though!

Comment: Hi Marc,  Thanks for the fast answer. I've tried this already, and unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem.  Adding the viewmodels in the constructor works just fine... but somehow it is not compatible with the usage of ItemsSource?  Thanks again anyway!

Comment: Hi all, indeed, there was something wrong behind the scenes (outside of the code show above). I can't recall exactly what I changed, but I've taken your remarks into account where needed.  In that way I consider your answer helpful. thanks a lot! Best regards.